Prove equilibrium point of system is asymptotically stable
I'm trying to solve a problem that goes like this:

Given the system
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned}
x'&=yx^3 \\
y'&=x^5
\end{aligned} \right.
$$
prove that its equilibrium solution is asymptotically stable.

Obviously its equilibrium is $(0,0)$ so I first tried linearization around it: Define $f(x,y) = (yx^3,x^5)$ and calculate its Jacobian Matrix  at $(0,0)$ but
$$
J_{f}(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
3yx^2 & x^3 \\
5x^4 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Therefore $J_{f}(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ so we can't conclude anything about stability.
Then I tried the usual Lyapunov function approach. Take for instance $V(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$, but in this case,
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}(x,y) 
= \bigl\langle \nabla V(x,y) \mid f(x,y) \bigr\rangle 
= \bigl\langle (x,y) \mid (yx^3, x^5) \bigr\rangle 
= y(x^4+x^5)
$$
which isn't negative definite on a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.
Honestly I can't seem to think of any suitable Lyapunov function for this system, and I believe it's mostly due to the fact most systems I've dealt with so far have a different kind of $f(x,y)$ function which allow to suitably have $\frac{dV}{dt}(x,y) < 0$ for any $x \neq 0$ when computing the inner product.
Thanks for your help in advance!

The line $x=0$ is composed of equilibria and so $(0,0)$ is not asymptotically stable.

The system is conservative. An integral constant is $\frac {x^3}{3}-\frac{y^2}{2}=C$.

The system is conservative so no sense in speak about asymptotic stability.
